# Neural Network learning in datasets that lie in small intervals

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to use Keras to learn a Neural Network that predicts the function $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}$. The network offers good performance when I try to learn the function over the intervals $[-10,10]$ and other similarly big intervals, but when I try to learn the function over $[-0.001,0.001]$, the neural network simply outputs the same value every time, or something extremely close to it when making a prediction. Does anyone have any idea why that is? I am currently trying out 3 hidden layers with the relu activation function, a dataset of size 10000, and 10 epochs.

Comment: Do you normalize your input data in your network?

Comment: How are you transforming the data when entering a different interval? Are you normalizing it?